# PDF.js rendering pages without forms

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using Mozilla PDF.js library and the demo works properly but the rendered PDF doesn't show forms / Acroforms.
Please help me out, how could I switch-on the forms and let the users to fulfill them.

**I use a canvas at HTML:**

```
  <body>
    <canvas id="pdf-render"></canvas>

    <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**And my main.js:**

```
const url = 'pdf.pdf';

let pdfDoc = null,
  pageNum = 1,
  pageIsRendering = false,
  pageNumIsPending = null;

const scale = 1,
  canvas = document.querySelector('#pdf-render'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Render the page
const renderPage = num => {
  pageIsRendering = true;

  // Get page
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(page => {
    // Set scale
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    const renderCtx = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport
    };

    page.render(renderCtx).promise.then(() => {
      pageIsRendering = false;

      if (pageNumIsPending !== null) {
        renderPage(pageNumIsPending);
        pageNumIsPending = null;
      }
    });
    
  });
};

// Check for pages rendering
const queueRenderPage = num => {
  if (pageIsRendering) {
    pageNumIsPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
};


// Get Document
pdfjsLib
  .getDocument(url)
  .promise.then(pdfDoc_ => {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;

    renderPage(pageNum);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Display error

  });
```

The PDF looks nice and appear but my main usage would be the forms. I'm sure it can be done, but I'm quite newbie at PDF.js lib.